# Counting/ Probability

Tags: probability

Please please please... explain this to me.

assume that a die is tossed twice and the numbers showing on the top faces are recorded in sequence Determine the elements in each of the given events

a- At least one number is a 5
b- at least one number is a 8
c-The sum of the numbers is less than 7
d- the sum of the numbers is greater than 8

Comment: Show us some work so far on the question and explain which step you're stuck at.

Comment: b should be easy-what is the highest number on a die?

Comment: well i actually dont even know where to start. i dont know how to word the answer.

Comment: ok.. so b would be 0?

Comment: Start by looking at all of the possible results.  With only 2 tosses of a single die, there aren't that many of them.

Comment: (1,1)(1,2)(1,3) and so on untill (6,6) ??

Comment: That is correct as long as you include $(2,1)$ as well as $(1,2)$.  You should have $6^2=36$ in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the events are just the values showing on the dice that satisfy the conditions. So for (b), there are no possible die rolls that meet the condition "at least one number is an 8", so the event is the empty set Ø. For (a), at least one number is a 5 if the first number is a 5 or the second number is a 5, so the events would look like {(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), ..., (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), ...} but I'll leave it to you to enumerate all of the correct elements (and there's one in there you need to look out for).

For (c) and (d), you'll need to write down the die rolls that sum to the appropriate amounts, and note that the two sets are complementary to each other - between the two of them, they cover all possible rolls.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its so simple! i just needed it to be explained with a better choice of words! also would i list both (1,2) &(2,1)

Comment: Yes. Rolling a 3 is twice as likely as rolling a 2, because 2 can only be rolled as (1, 1) while a 3 can be (1, 2) or (2, 1).